# jqgrid, autocomplete under several input boxes

Tags: jqgrid-php

For jqGrid, how to do autocomplete under several input boxes, namely A, B, C.  After the input A, autocomplete values provided by B need to have a reference from input A.

For the dataInit at input B, I can only get the original content of input A, not the current input one.

Any idea or link so that I can pay attention to.   Thanks

B/R
Gene Leung

Here is the code:

```
  ...
{ name:'order_no',
  index:'order_no',
  align:"center",
  width:80,
  editable:true,
  editoptions:
  {
    dataInit: function (elem) {
            myAutocomplete(elem, "./autoComplete.php?id=sales_no");
    },
    dataEvents: [
                  {  type: 'change',
                     fn: function(e) {
                        savedSalesNo = $(this).val();
                        //console.log( savedSalesNo );
                     }
                  } 
                ]
  }  
},
{ name:'item_no',
  index:'item_no',
  width:120,
  editable:true,
  editoptions:
  {
    dataInit: function (elem) {
    myAutocomplete(elem, "./autoComplete.php?id=sales_items&vchr_no=" + savedSalesNo);
    }
  }    
},
```

... php code: ...
   if isset($_GET["term"])) 
      $maskTP = $_GET['term'];
   else
      $maskTP = "";

$sWhere = "WHERE 1=1";

if($maskTP!='') {
      switch ($_GET["id"]) {
        case "sales_no":
           $sWhere.= " AND name LIKE '%$maskTP%'";
           $sSQL = "SELECT name AS order_no FROM sale_order ". $sWhere ." ORDER BY name";
               break;

```
    case "sales_items":
           $sWhere.= " AND name LIKE '%$maskTP%'";
           $sSQL = "SELECT name AS order_no FROM sale_order ". $sWhere ." ORDER BY name";
           break;   
    }
} 

$result = $db->Execute( $sSQL );
```

Comment: Posting the relevant code snippet would be nice!.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code snippet it will be helpful.

But looking at your question what i understand is you need to autocomplete in B based on A and so on.

So what you can do is while making ajax request for the B autocomplete check the value A and pass it in your call and perform your business logic.